# Custom Content Type on Documents SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, content-type

I'm trying to attach a custom content type to Document Library so that it's available to users whenever they upload a new document, they'll have the necessary columns visible. I'm struggling to staple this onto SharePoint 2010 and cannot really find a solution to this online.

Comment: Using Sharepoint UI or code or feature?

Comment: Ashish, I created the content type as a feature and activated it. What I need to do now, is "attached" this custom type to document libraries created with the creation of a new site. Can I do this via the ONET, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a contenttype to a list in a feature:

- Get a reference to the list
- Check if the list accepts contenttypes
- Add the contenttype

And in code:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["your list"];
list.AllowContentTypes = true;
SPContentType ct = web.AvailableContentTypes["your contenttype"];
list.ContentTypes.Add(ct);
```

This isn't production code, please add some checks and exception handling.